# How does GridSearchCV use cores?

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, neural-network, spyder

I'm doing a GridSearchCV, I had monitored the % of the core's and I have seen that when I was running a simple neural networ the 4 cores had the same %, but the when the grid search cv (n_jobs = 1) started there was a big confusion in the lines of the plot. Why? I Use Zorin

[image]

Below you can find the part of code where i do the gscv (but I changed n_jobs, inthe figure above it was used n_jobs = 1):

```
def build_regressor(opti, units1,units2, units3, acti, a, kern):

    model_TP = Sequential()
    model_TP.add(Dense(units = units1, input_shape = (X_train_TP.shape[1],), activation = acti, kernel_initializer = kern))
    model_TP.add(Dropout(a))
    model_TP.add(Dense(units = units2, activation = acti, kernel_initializer = kern))
    model_TP.add(Dropout(a))
    model_TP.add(Dense(units = units3, activation = acti, kernel_initializer = kern))
    model_TP.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear'))
    model_TP.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = opti, metrics = ['mse'])
    return model_TP

parameters ={'units1' : [50,100,150],
             'units2' : [50,100,150],
             'units3' : [50,100,150],
             'batch_size' : [50,100,250],
              'kern':['random_normal','glorot_uniform','random_uniform'],
              'acti':['relu','sigmoid','linear'],
              'opti':[tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.001),
                      tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)],
              'a' : [0.2,0.25]
                          }

regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn = build_regressor, verbose = 1)

gridSearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor,
                          param_grid=parameters,
                          cv=5, n_jobs = 4
                          )

grid_result = gridSearch.fit(X_train_TP, y_train_TP)

print('Grid Search Best score',gridSearch.best_score_)
print('Grid Search Best Parameters', gridSearch.best_params_)
print('Execution time',gridSearch.refit_time_)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **n_jobs**: int or None, optional (default=None)
>
> > Number of jobs to run in parallel. None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors. See Glossary for more details.

You should be in a parallel context by default.

```py
from sklearn.utils import _joblib                                                                                                                                                                  
backend = _joblib.parallel_backend(_joblib.joblib.parallel.DEFAULT_BACKEND)                                                                                                                       
backend.new_backend_and_jobs                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> (<joblib._parallel_backends.LokyBackend at 0x7f984f580dd8>, -1)
```

Hence the default n_jobs id `-1` so GridSearchCV uses all of your CPUs when no `n_jobs` is passed.

Comment: Yes I know this. But my question is different. Why when I'm using n_jobs by default there is the evolution of % of CPU used as in the picture?

Comment: @GabrieleValvo You mean the "mess" between the CPU usage when using only one job?

Comment: @ BernardoDuarte In the plot of the CPU usage you can see that on the left the 4 line as more or less flat, this period represent the CPU usage during a neural network training. On the left there are the four lines that have a trend that is really lively, this part is representative of the grid search with deafult n_jobs (n_jobs = 1). Why there is this difference in the CPU usage? I hope that the question is clear

Comment: @GabrieleValvo I'm not sure why this happens, I have only an hypothesis which is that since you've stated that there would be only one job, for each of them one different CPU were selected in a randomized manner, that can cause an imbalance in workload per CPU, as each call can be used by any CPU, I believe that you can test this by calling it multiple times and verifying if the graph changes randomly on the messy part. About the first part, I have another hypothesis, that the training is by default parallelized. But since I'm not sure I won't add it to the answer ;/